# How to find all positions of the maximum value in a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing, max

I have a list:

```
a = [32, 37, 28, 30, 37, 25, 27, 24, 35, 55, 23, 31, 55, 21, 40, 18, 50,
             35, 41, 49, 37, 19, 40, 41, 31]
```

max element is 55 (two elements on position 9 and 12)

I need to find on which position(s) the maximum value is situated. Please, help.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

```
>>> m = max(a)
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(a) if j == m]
[9, 12]
```

Comment: Nice short answer if you don't mind making multiple passes through the list -- which is likely.

Comment: Except the big 0 for this is 2n, the list is iterated through 2x, once to determine max, and another time to find the positions of the max. A for loop that tracks the current max and its position might be more efficient for really long lists.

Comment: @radtek big O is just n. leading coefficients are ignored in big O

Comment: Theoretically O(N) and O(2N) are the same but But practically, O(N) will definitely have a shorter running time, especially as N approaches infinity.

Answer (score 377):

```
a.index(max(a))
```

will tell you the index of the first instance of the largest valued element of list `a`.

Comment: This will only get you the first instance though and he asked for all the indexes where the largest value is found. You'd have to loop on that using slice to get the remaining list in each case and handling the exception when it's not found any longer.

Comment: I did mention that it would only give the first instance. If you want all of them, SilentGhost's solution is much prettier and less error prone.

Comment: At least as I came to it, the question explicitly asks for a list in the case of multiple maxima...

Comment: Technically, you could use this to get the first instance of the largest valued element and then set it to a ridiculously large negative number, and then find the next largest valued element, but that would be too complex.

Comment: @nmichaels Is there is any best way to get all positions of max value in a list than the accepted answer?

Comment: It is explicitly saying "all". Please don't spam, the goal here is to help people as quickly as possible not to get badges and reputation (remove your answer if you're really trying to help).

Comment: this is very good if you want an efficient way of finding max of a continuous list.

Answer (score 22):

The chosen answer (and most others) require at least two passes through the list.
Here's a one pass solution which might be a better choice for longer lists.

**Edited:** To address the two deficiencies pointed out by @John Machin. For (2) I attempted to optimize the tests based on guesstimated probability of occurrence of each condition and inferences allowed from predecessors. It was a little tricky figuring out the proper initialization values for `max_val` and `max_indices` which worked for all possible cases, especially if the max happened to be the first value in the list — but I believe it now does.

```
def maxelements(seq):
    ''' Return list of position(s) of largest element '''
    max_indices = []
    if seq:
        max_val = seq[0]
        for i,val in ((i,val) for i,val in enumerate(seq) if val >= max_val):
            if val == max_val:
                max_indices.append(i)
            else:
                max_val = val
                max_indices = [i]

    return max_indices
```

Comment: (1) The empty list handling needs attention. Should return `[]` as advertised ("Return list"). Code should be simply `if not seq: return []`. (2) Testing scheme in loop is sub-optimal: on average in random lists, condition `val < maxval` will be the most common but the above code takes 2 tests instead of one.

Comment: +1 to @John Machin's comment for catching the inconsistency with the docstring and not letting me get away with posting sub-optimal code. To be truthful, since an answer was already accepted, I lost a bit of motivation to continue working on my answer, since I assumed hardly anyone further would even look at it -- and it's so much longer than everyone else's.

Comment: @martineau: "accepted" answers are not necessarily "acceptable". I generally read all answers. Including your revision. Which does 3 tests now in the rare case of `==` instead of 2 -- your `elif` condition will always be true.

Comment: @John Machin: I got really inspired and revised it even further. Now it's down minimumal additional tests, plus a few other tweaks. Thanks for your comments and constructive criticisms. I caught the always True `elif` myself, FWIW. ;-)

Comment: @John Machin: Hmmm, your timing results seem to contradict my own, so I will remove what I said in my answer about timing so I can look into what's going on further. Thanks for the heads-up. Actually I think a "real" timing test would need to use random list values.

Comment: @John Machin: To follow up, yep, I made a dumb mistake when performing my timing tests, so the results were totally bogus. Anyway, with regards to your more accurate results, I guess there's almost no beating the built-ins for pure speed short of writing an external C module.

Comment: @JohnMachin this might still be the best solution if the input is an iterator rather than a list. I just [asked about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155065/find-all-items-with-maximum-value-produced-by-an-iterator).

Answer (score 19):

I came up with the following and it works as you can see with `max`, `min` and others functions over lists like these:

So, please consider the next example list find out the position of the **maximum** in the list `a`:

```
>>> a = [3,2,1, 4,5]
```

Using the **generator** `enumerate` and making a casting

```
>>> list(enumerate(a))
[(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

At this point, we can extract the position of *max* with

```
>>> max(enumerate(a), key=(lambda x: x[1]))
(4, 5)
```

The above tells us, the maximum is in the position 4 and his value is 5.

As you see, in the `key` argument, you can find the maximum over any iterable object by defining a lambda appropriate.

I hope that it contributes.

PD: As @PaulOyster noted in a comment. With `Python 3.x` the `min` and `max` allow a new keyword `default` that avoid the raise exception `ValueError` when argument is empty list. `max(enumerate(list), key=(lambda x:x[1]), default = -1)`

Comment: This is a better solution, since it involves a single pass.  A few comments, though: 1. no need to list() the enumeration, 2. lambda better be parenthesized, 3. min() and max() now have a default parameter (which is returned on empty input), so can use it (default=-1, for example)  to avoid a ValueError exception, and 4. please change to max(), as this was the original question.

Comment: about 3 item, yes, it just works with Python 3.x. I'll mention that. And fixed everything else. ;)

Comment: This would only find the position of one of the maximum valued elements (the first) when it occurs more than once in the list—so doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: This solution is slightly different from what OP asked but if we just want to find the max index in one pass this seems to be a better approach. I would suggest to have `default = (None, None)` as it fits the return type in case I am assigning to some variables like `max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(list), key=(lambda x:x[1]), default = (None, None))`

Answer (score 14):

Also a solution, which gives **only the first appearance**, can be achieved by using `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a_np = np.array(a)
>>> np.argmax(a_np)
9
```

Answer (score 11):

I can't reproduce the @SilentGhost-beating performance quoted by @martineau. Here's my effort with comparisons:

=== maxelements.py ===

```
a = [32, 37, 28, 30, 37, 25, 27, 24, 35, 55, 23, 31, 55, 21, 40, 18, 50,
             35, 41, 49, 37, 19, 40, 41, 31]
b = range(10000)
c = range(10000 - 1, -1, -1)
d = b + c

def maxelements_s(seq): # @SilentGhost
    ''' Return list of position(s) of largest element '''
    m = max(seq)
    return [i for i, j in enumerate(seq) if j == m]

def maxelements_m(seq): # @martineau
    ''' Return list of position(s) of largest element '''
    max_indices = []
    if len(seq):
        max_val = seq[0]
        for i, val in ((i, val) for i, val in enumerate(seq) if val >= max_val):
            if val == max_val:
                max_indices.append(i)
            else:
                max_val = val
                max_indices = [i]
    return max_indices

def maxelements_j(seq): # @John Machin
    ''' Return list of position(s) of largest element '''
    if not seq: return []
    max_val = seq[0] if seq[0] >= seq[-1] else seq[-1]
    max_indices = []
    for i, val in enumerate(seq):
        if val < max_val: continue
        if val == max_val:
            max_indices.append(i)
        else:
            max_val = val
            max_indices = [i]
    return max_indices
```

Results from a beat-up old laptop running Python 2.7 on Windows XP SP3:

```
>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"import maxelements as me" "me.maxelements_s(me.a)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.88 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"import maxelements as me" "me.maxelements_m(me.a)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.1 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"import maxelements as me" "me.maxelements_j(me.a)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.51 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"import maxelements as me;a100=me.a*100" "me.maxelements_s(a100)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 535 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"import maxelements as me;a100=me.a*100" "me.maxelements_m(a100)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 558 usec per loop

>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"import maxelements as me;a100=me.a*100" "me.maxelements_j(a100)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 489 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the numpy package:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(a)
maximum_indices = np.where(A==max(a))
```

This will return an numpy array of all the indices that contain the max value

if you want to turn this to a list:

```
maximum_indices_list = maximum_indices.tolist()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
a = [32, 37, 28, 30, 37, 25, 27, 24, 35, 
         55, 23, 31, 55, 21, 40, 18, 50,
         35, 41, 49, 37, 19, 40, 41, 31]

import pandas as pd

pd.Series(a).idxmax()

9
```

That is how I usually do it.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> max(enumerate([1,2,3,32,1,5,7,9]),key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> (3, 32)
```

Comment: This is wrong. Try to put the maximum number in the middle of the list.

Comment: This is wrong. Question says "find all positions of the maximum value".

Answer (score 5):

[@shash answered this elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33144647/1587329)

> A Pythonic way to find the index of the maximum list element would be
>
> ```
> position = max(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
> ```

Which does *one pass*. Yet, it is slower than the solution by @Silent_Ghost and, even more so, @nmichaels:

```
for i in s m j n; do echo $i;  python -mtimeit -s"import maxelements as me" "me.maxelements_${i}(me.a)"; done
s
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.13 usec per loop
m
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.99 usec per loop
j
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.71 usec per loop
n
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Just one line:

```
idx = max(range(len(a)), key = lambda i: a[i])
```

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't return ALL indexes, just the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the max value and the indexes it appears at:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> a = [32, 37, 28, 30, 37, 25, 27, 24, 35, 55, 23, 31, 55, 21, 40, 18, 50, 35, 41, 49, 37, 19, 40, 41, 31]
>>> for i, x in enumerate(a):
...     d[x].append(i)
... 
>>> k = max(d.keys())
>>> print k, d[k]
55 [9, 12]
```

---

Later: for the satisfaction of @SilentGhost

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> import heapq
>>> 
>>> def popper(heap):
...     while heap:
...         yield heapq.heappop(heap)
... 
>>> a = [32, 37, 28, 30, 37, 25, 27, 24, 35, 55, 23, 31, 55, 21, 40, 18, 50, 35, 41, 49, 37, 19, 40, 41, 31]
>>> h = [(-x, i) for i, x in enumerate(a)]
>>> heapq.heapify(h)
>>> 
>>> largest = heapq.heappop(h)
>>> indexes = [largest[1]] + [x[1] for x in takewhile(lambda large: large[0] == largest[0], popper(h))]
>>> print -largest[0], indexes
55 [9, 12]
```

Comment: you do realise how inefficient this is?

Comment: Rationalizations: (1) "Premature optimization is the ... etc." (2) It probably doesn't matter. (3) It's still a good solution. Maybe I'll recode it to use `heapq` -- finding the max there would be trivial.

Comment: while I'd love to see your `heapq` solution, I doubt it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Similar idea with a list comprehension but without enumerate

```
m = max(a)
[i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] == m]
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but note that this doesn't look really nice and won't perform well: iterating through the indices instead of through the list is very awkward in Python, you try to avoid this. As well, it's certainly slower than the solution with enumerate because of the `a[i]` call.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the indices of the largest `n` numbers in a list called `data`, you can use Pandas [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
pd.Series(data).sort_values(ascending=False).index[0:n]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple single-pass solution.

```
import math
nums = [32, 37, 28, 30, 37, 25, 55, 27, 24, 35, 55, 23, 31]

max_val = -math.inf
res = []

for i, val in enumerate(nums):
    if(max_val < val):
        max_val = val
        res = [i]
    elif(max_val == val):
        res.append(i)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator

def max_positions(iterable, key=None, reverse=False):
  if key is None:
    def key(x):
      return x
  if reverse:
    better = operator.lt
  else:
    better = operator.gt

  it = enumerate(iterable)
  for pos, item in it:
    break
  else:
    raise ValueError("max_positions: empty iterable")
    # note this is the same exception type raised by max([])
  cur_max = key(item)
  cur_pos = [pos]

  for pos, item in it:
    k = key(item)
    if better(k, cur_max):
      cur_max = k
      cur_pos = [pos]
    elif k == cur_max:
      cur_pos.append(pos)

  return cur_max, cur_pos

def min_positions(iterable, key=None, reverse=False):
  return max_positions(iterable, key, not reverse)
```

```
>>> L = range(10) * 2
>>> L
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> max_positions(L)
(9, [9, 19])
>>> min_positions(L)
(0, [0, 10])
>>> max_positions(L, key=lambda x: x // 2, reverse=True)
(0, [0, 1, 10, 11])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is not as sophisticated as the answers posted earlier but it will work:

```
m = max(a)
n = 0    # frequency of max (a)
for number in a :
    if number == m :
        n = n + 1
ilist = [None] * n  # a list containing index values of maximum number in list a.
ilistindex = 0
aindex = 0  # required index value.    
for number in a :
    if number == m :
        ilist[ilistindex] = aindex
        ilistindex = ilistindex + 1
    aindex = aindex + 1

print ilist
```

*ilist* in the above code would contain all the positions of the maximum number in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in various ways.

The old conventional way is,

```
maxIndexList = list() #this list will store indices of maximum values
maximumValue = max(a) #get maximum value of the list
length = len(a)       #calculate length of the array

for i in range(length): #loop through 0 to length-1 (because, 0 based indexing)
    if a[i]==maximumValue: #if any value of list a is equal to maximum value then store its index to maxIndexList
        maxIndexList.append(i)

print(maxIndexList) #finally print the list
```

Another way without calculating the length of the list and storing maximum value to any variable,

```
maxIndexList = list()
index = 0 #variable to store index
for i in a: #iterate through the list (actually iterating through the value of list, not index )
    if i==max(a): #max(a) returns a maximum value of list.
        maxIndexList.append(index) #store the index of maximum value
index = index+1 #increment the index

print(maxIndexList)
```

We can do it in Pythonic and smart way! Using list comprehension just in one line,

```
maxIndexList = [i for i,j in enumerate(a) if j==max(a)] #here,i=index and j = value of that index
```

All my codes are in Python 3.