# Position in an list?

Tags: python, list, position

I will check if a word exists in a list.
How can I show the position of this word?

Comment: You do it by searching for folks who already asked this question and reading the answers already presented here.

Comment: Either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/python-get-position-in-list or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989016/how-to-find-positions-of-the-list-maximum will answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get item's position in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/how-to-get-items-position-in-a-list)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
list = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
try:
   print list.index("word1")
except ValueError:
   print "word1 not in list."
```

This piece of code will print `0`, because that's the index of the first occurrence of `"word1"`

Comment: Personally, I think the exception approach is valid iff you expect the word to be in the array, but maybe that's just me. Otherwise, you could test for the presence of the word in the list before finding its index, as shown by jleedev.

Comment: @Lee-Man he asked for a function which would return the index of a value in a list, and I gave that to him, with all use cases. I agree that jleedev's solution is more comfortable, but I tried to provide all use cases for `.index`

Comment: IMHO using `.index()` inside a `try/except` is the most efficient approach since it only searches for a match once, and is totally "Pythonic" in the sense that it employs the [EAFP ](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) style of programming.

Comment: @Lee-Man: Ignoring double lookups, if exceptional cases are rare, then code using exceptions will have better average performance than the alternative.

Answer (score 3):

To check *if* an object is in a list, use the `in` operator:

```
>>> words = ['a', 'list', 'of', 'words']
>>> 'of' in words
True
>>> 'eggs' in words
False
```

Use the `index` method of a list to find out *where* in the list, but be prepared to handle the exception:

```
>>> words.index('of')
2
>>> words.index('eggs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'eggs' is not in list
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `['hello', 'world'].index('world')`

Answer (score 2):

The following code:

```
sentence=["I","am","a","boy","i","am","a","girl"]
word="am"
if word in sentence:
    print( word, " is in the sentence")
    for i, j in enumerate(sentence):
        if j == word:
            print("'"+word+"'","is in position",i+1)
```

would produce this output:

```
"am" is in position 1
"am" is in position 5
```

This is because in python the indexing starts at 0

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 2):

using enumeration - to find all occurences of given string in list

```
listEx=['the','tiger','the','rabit','the','the']
print([index for index,ele in enumerate(listEx) if ele=='the'])
```

output

```
[0, 2, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want indexof. From [here](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html):

> operator.indexOf(a, b)¶
>       Return the index of the first of occurrence of b in a.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the word is named for example "Monday":

You will need a list as your initial database:

```
myList = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Monday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
```

Then you need to loop through your list one by one to the end using for, next(), iter() and len() function:

```
myIter = iter(myList)
for i in range(0, len(myList)):
next_item = next(myIter)
```

Now while looping, you need to check if the wanted word exists and wherever it exists, print it:

```
if next_item == "Monday":
    print(i)
```

Altogether:

```
myList = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Monday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
myIter = iter(myList)
for i in range(0, len(myList)):
    next_item = next(myIter)
    if next_item == "Monday":
        print(i)
```

Since there are two Mondays in this list, the result for this example will be: 
0
2