# How to find index of an element in Python list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find positions of the list maximum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989016/how-to-find-positions-of-the-list-maximum)

A question from homework:
Deﬁne a function `censor(words,nasty)` that takes a list of words, and
replaces all the words appearing in nasty with the word CENSORED, and
returns the censored list of words.

```
>>> censor([’it’,’is’,’raining’], [’raining’])
[’it’,’is’,’CENSORED’]
```

I see solution like this:

1. find an index of `nasty`
2. replace words matching that index
   with `"CENSORED"`

but i get stuck on finding the index..

Comment: @mart: OP says it's homework.

Comment: @Silent: OK, sorry if it was voluntary. See the link in my comment about meta tags attached to @z4y4ts's answer.

Comment: @martineau: well, homework is not in that list and it does seem alive and kicking. I should also note that I deeply despise those misguided attempts in social engineering originating from our corporate overlords.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Did you read the part where @Aaronut wrote "The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question"? which is the crux of why they're looked upon poorly. How many regular users do you think ever search for the tag "homework" -- so what good is it?

Comment: @Silent: [homework] *is* in that list: "the homework tag, like other so-called "meta" tags, is now discouraged." http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812

Comment: @Roger: is it not just a personal opinion of Joel's? I don't see how this question is any different from 5276 others homework questions.

Comment: @Silent: It is not just Joel's opinion: [ **"Meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged."** ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60015)  This is site *policy.*  See the two criteria given: 1) can [homework] work as the only tag on the question? no. 2) does it mean different things to different people? yes, it isn't uncommon for people to retag with [homework] to mean "basics" or "beginner".

Comment: @Roger: so then it clearly doesn't apply to this question, does it? it's not the only tag on a the question, and the reason I put it there is the OP opening: *A question from homework: *. I think the meta tags are extremely useful, take OP for example 12 question, 0 answers, 7 homework tags, probably would have about a dozen of beginner tag too. I'd prefer to have this information not to waste too much time.

Comment: @Silent: Re-read the criteria listed in the blog post; you misunderstand how to apply it.  If you don't want to answer this question, then *don't answer it.* But also don't try to brand the question or the poster with your own subjective viewpoint by tagging as [homework] or [beginner].

Comment: @Roger: **I don't brand anyone with anything, OP said it was a homework question and so I tagged the question accordingly**. Maybe "official policies" would be more useful and respected, if the there wasn't so many idiotic of them around and their defence wouldn't deteriorate into civil war.

Comment: @Silent: If the OP said "I want to start a subjective discussion...", would you tag as [subjective] and [discussion]?  If someone says "I'm writing my PhD thesis about X...", would you tag as [homework] or [X]?

Comment: @Roger: I did vote to close this question if that's what you're implying.

Comment: No, that is not what I'm saying at all.  I'm saying picking out a particular word from the post is not enough to tag with that word.

Comment: @Silent: When someone flat out says "this isn't homework", [why do you tag it as homework?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4099042/54262)  Apparently it's *not* the content of the question that matters for you to tag [homework], and that shows use as a meta-tag.

Comment: @Roger: are you kidding me? how's exam preparation is not a homework? and I have already said I see meta tags as a useful tool in the community.

Comment: @Silent: Because it's not.  You seem to want to tag anything done by a student as homework, regardless of what is actually asked or whether it was actually assigned by a teacher.  Why not include interview preparation and questions as [homework]?  It's certainly work done at home with the goal of self-improvement rather than solving a "real problem."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't have to operate with indexes here. Just iterate over `words` list and check if the word is listed in `nasty`. If it is append `'CENSORED'` to the result list, else append the word itself.

Or you can involve [list comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) and [conditional expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) to get more elegant version:

Comment: It’s considered extremely bad manners to solve homework questions for other people. It negates the learning effect, is unfair to other pupils and it pisses tutors off.

Comment: Oops, sorry for that, I haven't seen these homework questions before. Will it be ok if I remove the code and leave only comments?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: That may become harder given that meta tags, like "homework", are now being discouraged -- see [*The Death of Meta Tags*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags). Of course there are tradeoffs, but overall I personally tend to agree with the reasoning.

Comment: absolutely. Help is always appreciated, *including* for homework questions.

Answer (score 39):

You can find the index of any element of a `list` by using the `.index` method.

```
>>> l=['a','b','c']
>>> l.index('b')
1
```

Comment: Unless there are two cases of 'b' in the list, in which case you will only get the first one. That could be a problem with this question.

Comment: Can't believe I had to scroll all the way down here to find this....

Answer (score 1):

Your approach might work, but it’s unnecessarily complicated.

Python allows a very simple syntax to check whether something is contained in a list:

```
censor = [ 'bugger', 'nickle' ]
word = 'bugger'
if word in censor: print 'CENSORED'
```

With that approach, simply walk over your list of words and test for each words whether it’s in the `censor` list.

To walk over your list of words, you can use the `for` loop. Since you might need to modify the current word, use an index, like so:

```
for index in len(words)):
   print index, words[index]
```

Now all you need to do is put the two code fragments together.

Comment: ... and then score some brownie points by turning the above O(#words * #nastywords) algorithm into a O(#words). :)

Comment: @janneb: Sure this works? All I can achieve is expected (!) time O(#words + #censor) – by converting the censored words list to a `set`.

Comment: Well, yes, you're right. My point was that one can, by the use of a set as you point out (or dict for older python versions), turn this quadratic algo into a linear one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the handy built-in [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function to step through the items in the list. For example:

```
def censor(words, nasty):
    for i,word in enumerate(words):
       if word...
```