# Sequence of vowels count

Tags: python, regex, nlp

This is not a homework question, it is an exam preparation question.

I should deﬁne a function `syllables(word)` that counts the number of syllables in
A word in the following way:

• a maximal sequence of vowels is a syllable;

• a ﬁnal **e** in a word is not a syllable (or the vowel sequence it is a part
Of).

I do not have to deal with any special cases, such as a ﬁnal **e** in a
One-syllable word (e.g., ’be’ or ’bee’).

```
>>> syllables(’honour’)
2
>>> syllables(’decode’)
2
>>> syllables(’oiseau’)
2
```

Should I use regular expression here or just list comprehension ?

Comment: What is a "maximal sequence of vowels?"

Comment: sorry, we aren't going to make a separate `[examp-preparaton]` tag for you

Comment: Does "a ﬁnal e in a word is not a syllable (or the vowel sequence it is a part of)." mean that "toe" has no syllables, or does the restriction just mean that a final e does not affect the syllable count of the word?

Comment: @SilentGhost I don't want any separate tag for the question, I just want people to know that solution code is desirable since this is not a homework where people usually give suggestions and not the answers.
@jball - the restriction just mean that a final e does not affect the syllable count of the word.
@Matt Ball - sequence of vowels is two or more vowels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find regular expressions natural for this question.  (I think a non-regex answer would take more coding.  I use two string methods, 'lower' and 'endswith' to make the answer more clear.)

```
import re
def syllables(word):
    word = word.lower()
    if word.endswith('e'):
        word = word[:-1]
    count = len(re.findall('[aeiou]+', word))
    return count

for word in ('honour', 'decode', 'decodes', 'oiseau', 'pie'):
    print word, syllables(word)
```

Which prints:

```
honour 2
decode 2
decodes 3
oiseau 2
pie 1
```

Note that 'decodes' has one more syllable than 'decode' (which is strange, but fits your definition).

Question.  How does this help you?  Isn't the point of the study question that you work through it yourself?  You may get more benefit in the future by posting a failed attempt in your question, so you can learn exactly where you are lacking.

Comment: @novalis.  I did not include 'y' due to the simplistic definition in the question which did not want to deal with special cases.  I consider 'y' a special case in that it is sometimes a vowel and sometimes not.  However, if the questioner wants 'y' to be a vowel, insert 'y' into the regular expression.

Comment: @novalis  Here's another hard one:  'Maya'

Comment: I know it's more efficient to study a question myself ...but not this one. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use regexps - most languages will let you count the number of matches of a regexp in a string.

Then special-case the terminal-e by checking the right-most match group.

Comment: you could probably hack in some negative lookahead or something for the final e.

Comment: You're better off not trying to force the final-e handling into the same regex.  Just remove any final vowel sequence if it ends with 'e' with `re.sub` before performing the count.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard, according to @Gusto's comment, you would only want to trim the final 'e', if any exists, not the final vowel sequence. Confusing specs, I know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regex is the right solution here.

It seems pretty straightforward to write this treating each string as a list.

Comment: depending on what that "final e" restriction is, it seems like a regex is the most trivial solution.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you define "most trivial"

Comment: It's not hard to come up with a 4-state DFA for it, and I haven't tried to come up with a smaller one. Given the three symbol types (vowels except e, e, non-vowels) the regex basically writes itself.

Comment: Er, just wrote it out - that should be a 3-state DFA.

Comment: I did the same, and you are right, regex is pretty easy, if you don't care about sometimes y and w.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers:

`[abc]` matches `a`, `b` or `c`.

A `+` after a regex token allows the token to match once or more

`$` matches the end of the string.

`(?<=x)` matches the current position only if the previous character is an `x`.

`(?!x)` matches the current position only if the next character is not an `x`.

**EDIT:**

I just saw your comment that since this is not homework, actual code is requested.
Well, then:

```
[aeiou]+(?!(?<=e)$)
```

If you don't want to count final vowel sequences that end in `e` at all (like the `u` in `tongue` or the `o` in `toe`), then use

```
[aeiou]+(?=[^aeiou])|[aeiou]*[aiou]$
```

I'm sure you'll be able to figure out how it works if you read the explanation above.

Comment: That expression matches the final 'u' in 'tongue', which i would consider correct, but the question does not: "a ﬁnal e in a word is not a syllable (or the vowel sequence it is a part of)".

Comment: Yes, I'm still waiting for Gusto to answer jball's question... might just edit in an alternative...

Comment: he included the answer to my question in a long comment, "the restriction just mean that a final e does not affect the syllable count of the word." so your solution looks correct to me.

Comment: @jball: Ah, thanks, I hadn't noticed. Well, too late, I've already written a new additional solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer without regular expressions.  My real answer (also posted) uses regular expressions.  Untested code:

```
def syllables(word):
    word = word.lower()
    if word.endswith('e'):
        word = word[:-1]
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    in_vowel_group = False
    vowel_groups = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:
            if not in_vowel_group:
                in_vowel_group = True
                vowel_groups += 1
        else:
            in_vowel_group = False
    return vowel_groups
```

Answer (score 0):

Both ways work.  You said yourself that it was for exam preparation.  Use whichever is going to be on the exam.  If they're both on the exam, use which you need more practice for.   Just remember:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. ~Jamie Zawinski

So in my opinion, don't use regex unless you need the practice.

Comment: Except that this case is (probably) precisely what regexes are good for. The problem arises when regexes are the only tool in your toolbox, and you try to use the proverbial hammer to drive a screw.

Comment: @jball Too true.  That's why it's only my opinion to not use regex :)

Comment: I would recommend using the one you're most comfortable with.  Regexs can be difficult to debug if you don't have a lot of experience, but they can provide the simplest solution. List comprehension, on the other hand, can be the easiest to implement, but the solution might be messy.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions would be way too complex, and a list comprehension probably wouldn't be robust enough. You will probably be able to solve this easily using a grammar lexer like [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).  Give it a shot!

Comment: ...a grammar lexer is way too complicated for an exam question. I don't see what's wrong with regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex that matches a,e,i,o, or u, convert the string to a list, then iterate through the list... 1 for first true, 1 for next false, 2 for next true, 2 for next false, etc.

To handle the case where the last letter is 'e' following a consonant (as in ate), just check the last two letters of the word before you start. If they match that pattern truncate the final e and process as normal.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern works for your definition:

```
(?!e$)([aeiouy]+)
```

Just count how many times it occurs.