# Finding the largest in a list (string,number) python

Tags: python, string

I have a list in  the following format:

```
[('car  crash  killed', 95), ('car  accident  crash', 86), ('disaster  police  car', 45)]
```

I want to extract the string/sentence with the largest number and print it in a text file. In this case, the output will be:

```
car crash killed
```

If there two or more strings/sentences with the same largest number, I want to extract all of them.For example:

```
[('car  crash  killed', 95), ('car  accident  crash', 95), ('disaster  police  car', 45)]
```

Output:

```
car crash killed
car accident crash
```

How to extract?

Comment: Can you edit your code to show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: This is merger of a few questions, the dupe, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989016/how-to-find-all-positions-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-list for example.

Answer (score 2):

Use `max` to get item with largest value:

```
lst = [('car  crash  killed', 95), ('car  accident  crash', 86), ('disaster  police  car', 45)]

print(max(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])[0])
# car  crash  killed
```

Now, to return all max value items, basically apply the same logic. Get `max_value` and return all items with the `max_value` using a list-comprehension like below:

```
lst = [('car  crash  killed', 95), ('car  accident  crash', 95), ('disaster  police  car', 45)]

max_value = max(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
print([x[0] for x in lst if x[1] == max_value])

# ['car  crash  killed', 'car  accident  crash']
```

Comment: OP requested returning all maximal valued matches, you return just one.

Comment: Thanks! @Austin. It's returning the max, I'll try to work around with it to get all the max values

Comment: @kabanus I suppose it now works for what is requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

dictionary = dict([('car  crash  killed', 95), ('car  accident  crash', 95), ('disaster  police  car', 45)])
counter = Counter(dictionary)
max_value = counter.most_common(1)[0][1]
print(max_value)

result = list(string for string, count in counter.most_common() if count == max_value)
print(result)
```

Comment: This fails to return all matches.

Comment: Yes, it is similar to @Austin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given a list with repeated values (96):

```
data = [('car  crash  killed', 95),
        ('car  accident  crash', 86),
        ('disaster  police  car', 45),
        ('road', 95)]
```

Then you sort it by the value and select the highest ones:

```
data = sorted([(y, x) for x, y in data], reverse=True)
out = []
highest = data[0][0]
for y, x in data:
    if y == highest:
        out.append(x)
print(out)

['road', 'car  crash  killed']
```

This can be simplified with a list comprehension:

```
data = sorted([(y, x) for x, y in data], reverse=True)

highest = data[0][0]
out = [x for y,x in data if y==highest]
print(out)

['road', 'car  crash  killed']
```

Comment: Thanks! @joaquin. It is giving all the values that has the maximum value.