# How to find the index list position in the list

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
pola2 = [['%3C','%28'],['%3C','document.cookie','%3B'],['%3C','%28','%27','4'],['%3C','document.cookie','%3B','4','5'],['%3C','document.cookie','%3B','4','5','6']]
#find the longest list in list
a = max(pola2, key=len)
print a
#result ['%3C', 'document.cookie', '%3B', '4', '5', '6']
#how if end of result is index "4" or position "5"
```

How do I print the result of `print a` as it appears in index 4 or position 5 in the `pola2` list?

Comment: did you try `pola2.index(max(pola2, key=len))` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all positions of the maximum value in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989016/how-to-find-all-positions-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-list)

Comment: Han solo, thanks its work but how if the result is 5 not (index) 4?

Comment: @Goviella just add 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try with the code bellow:

```
pola2 = [['%3C','%28'],['%3C','document.cookie','%3B'],['%3C','%28','%27','4'],['%3C','document.cookie','%3B','4','5'],['%3C','document.cookie','%3B','4','5','6']]
a = max(pola2, key=len)
print pola2.index(a)
```

Should work fine. And the question is kind of duplicated, see: [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)