# Finding the max value and count how many times it appears in a list without using max or count function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am currently studying python, and I am struggling to find an answer to an assignment. I need to create a list from a user input, then find the highest temperature of the input and count how many times that temperature appears from the input. Finally I should output the highest temperature and how many times it appears.

```
input_temps = []
for i in range(int(input("Enter the tmeperature here: "))):
    input_temps.append(int(input()))

print(input_temps)
```

this is what I have so far.

Edit: I am not allowed to use any max or count functions

Comment: Looks like you take first temperature value as the count itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all positions of the maximum value in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989016/how-to-find-all-positions-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-list)

Comment: @Piron They don't need the positions, and going that route would make things unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Which part of the problem are you struggling with? Your title isn't very representative/accurate, by the way, since creating the list is the one thing you already have figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: This was before they changed the question to rule out those functions, but a solution without is at the end)

You can use `max` and `count` functions. And better improve the input messages:

```
input_temps = []
for i in range(int(input("Enter the number of temperatures: "))):
    input_temps.append(int(input("Enter a temperature: ")))
print(input_temps)
max_temp = max(input_temps)
print(f'{max_temp=}')
max_temp_count = input_temps.count(max_temp)
print(f'{max_temp_count=}')
```

Demo:

```
Enter the number of temperatures: 3
Enter a temperature: 5
Enter a temperature: 4
Enter a temperature: 5
[5, 4, 5]
max_temp=5
max_temp_count=2
```

Since you now asked for a version without using `max`:

```
input_temps = []
max_temp = None
max_temp_count = None
for i in range(int(input("Enter the number of temperatures: "))):
    temp = int(input("Enter a temperature: "))
    input_temps.append(temp)
    if max_temp is None or temp > max_temp:
        max_temp = temp
        max_temp_count = 1
    elif temp == max_temp:
        max_temp_count += 1
print(f'{max_temp=}')
print(f'{max_temp_count=}')
```

Comment: What would the be the more difficult way without using the max_function?

Comment: When i run this it doesn't go past the entering of the input "Enter the number of temperatures". i am a complete noob when it comes to python, i can understand the code and how it should run but i still am struggling

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't go past"?

Comment: I was expecting the code to then ask me to enter the temperatures to add to the list then find the max and count and finally output those answers, so once i clicked enter the code stops

Comment: I don't think that's possible, unless you used the second version and answered the first question with `0`.

Comment: I used the second version only and when asked to enter the number of temperatures i entered '5' pressed enter then the code stops

Comment: That can't be right. I think you changed the code somehow.

Comment: Yes you are right, what would be the next step to print the output on screen to say what temperature is the highest with how many times in appears?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to enter all the temperatures, either space or comma separated:

```
temps = input('Enter the temperatures here: ')

temps_list = [float(s) for s in temps.split(',')]

hg = max(temps_list)
cnt = temps.count(hg)
print(f'List of temperatures: {temps}\
      \nThe highest temperature is {hg}, which appears {cnt} times.')
```

Working example:

```
Enter the temperatures here: 3,1.1,2,3.2,6,2.2,6,5.7,5
List of temperatures: [3.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.2, 6.0, 2.2, 6.0, 5.7, 5.0]      
The highest temperature is 6.0, which appears 2 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the max temperature in the list, just use `max(input_temps)`. After that, you can set up a counter variable starting at 0 and use a for loop that iterates through each element in the list and compares it to the max temperature. If they are equal, just add 1 to the counter.