# python nested dict get dict object with max key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dd object:

```
dd = {'111': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '0'}}, '222': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '2'}}, '333': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '2'}}, '121': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '4'}}}
```

with similar `cid`.

I need to find the max dd object with `num`:

desired:

desired: `{'121': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '4'}}}`

I know how to iterate over a nested dict to find the max key

```
 print(max(int(z['num']) for d in dd.values() for z in d.values()))  # 4
```

^ but this gives the value of `num` and not the complete object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all positions of the maximum value in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989016/how-to-find-all-positions-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-list)

Comment: `max(dd.items(), key=lambda i: int(i[1]['10']['num']))`.

Comment: @ekhumoro that is clever but what if `10` is not common?

Comment: @JackJee Does the 2nd level dict have more than one item?

Comment: `dict([max(dd.items(), key=lambda i: int(list(i[1].values())[0]['num']))])`.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes it could have multiple items

Comment: @JackJee In that case, please show a more realistic example. It's unhelpful to keep changing the conditions every time someone gives a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
dd = {'111': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '0'}}, '222': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '2'}},
      '333': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '2'}}, '121': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '4'}}}

pair = max([(int(v['num']), val, key) for key, val in dd.items() for v in val.values()], key=lambda item: item[0])
print({pair[2]: pair[1]})
```

output

```
{'121': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '4'}}}
```

Comment: Changing the `dict` object position, gives the incorrect result. For example on this input data `dd = {'111': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '4'}}, '222': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '2'}},
      '333': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '2'}}, '444': {'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '3'}}}` it gives incorrect result

Comment: @JackJee I have tested the code using your `dd` and got the expected result: `{'10': {'cid': '555', 'num': '3'}}`

Comment: yes, and that is incorrect. see there is a `num:4` present in the `dd`

Comment: @JackJee Bug was solved. However the code is not very nice..