# Fastest way to find all elements that maximize / minimize a function in a Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, performance

Let's use a simple example: say I have a list of lists

```
ll = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

and I want to find **all** longest lists, which means all lists that maximize the `len` function. Of course we can do

```
def func(x):
    return len(x)
maxlen = func(max(ll, key=lambda x: func(x)))
res = [l for l in ll if func(l) == maxlen]
print(res)
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

But I wonder if there are more efficient way to do this, especially when the function is very expensive or the list is very long. Any suggestions?

Comment: this is `O(n)`, can't get any better. There might be a little faster alternative, like you don't need the `func(x)`, just replace it straight up with `len(x)`, but other than that, I don't think so.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Isn't this ``O(2n)``?

Comment: You have to analyze each element in the list to be sure you don't skip a potential maximum_element, so as @Mahrkeenerh said it cannot be better than `O(n)`

Comment: Constants are ignored within O notation. You could make it a little faster if you build your output list while finding the max value, but that's pretty much the same

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh But still, I computed the function for each elements twice. Is there anyway to only compute once?

Comment: as suggested in the answers below, yes - build your list while finding the max element, or cache the results, so even if it is expensive, the second pass will be a LOT faster.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989016/how-to-find-all-positions-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-list The first answer is wrong but there are a lot of other interesting answers there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a computer science/algorithms perspective, this is a very classical "reduce" problem.

so, pseudocode. It's honestly very straightforward.

```
metric():= a mapping from elements to non-negative numbers

winner = []
maxmetric = 0

for element in ll:
  if metric(element) larger than maxmetric:
    winner = [ element ]
    maxmetric = metric(element)
  else if metric(element) equal to maxmetric:
    append element to winner
```

Comment: An even more generalist solution is to set `maxmetric = metric(first element of ll)`, just in case the metric is able to return negative numbers.

Comment: that depends on *how* expensive that metric is, but yeah, that's one way of doing it. (metrics in the math sense of the word: non-negative by definition)

Answer (score 3):

*when the function is very expensive*

Note that you do compute `func(x)` for each element twice, first there

```
maxlen = func(max(ll, key=lambda x: func(x)))
```

then there

```
res = [l for l in ll if func(l) == maxlen]
```

so it would be beneficial to store what was already computed. [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) allow that easily just replace

```
def func(x):
    return len(x)
```

using

```
import functools
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def func(x):
    return len(x)
```

However, beware as due to way how data are stored argument(s) must be hashable, so in your example you would first need convert list e.g. to `tuple`s i.e.

```
ll = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
```

See descripiton in docs for further discussion

Answer (score 3):

Is not OK use `dictionary` like below, *(this is `O(n)`)*

```
ll = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]

from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(list)

for l in ll:
    dct[len(l)].append(l)
    
dct[max(dct)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]


>>> dct
defaultdict(list, {2: [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]], 3: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]})
```

OR use `setdefault` and without `defaultdict` like below:

```
ll = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]

dct = {}
for l in ll:
    dct.setdefault(len(l), []).append(l)
```

Output:

```
>>> dct
{2: [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]], 3: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]}
```