# Find the index of the rightmost maximum value in a list of numbers without using iterations

Tags: python, list

For `nums = [8,5,15,2,15,7,3,4]`, using `nums.index(max(nums)` returns 2, the index of the first/leftmost max value. I want such a simple code to find the index of the last/rightmost max value, 4 here.

Using iterations like `[i for i,j in enumerate(nums) if j == max(nums)][-1]` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989016/how-to-find-all-positions-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-list) is too heavy.
One can use `len(nums)-1-nums[::-1].index(max(nums))` but is there a simpler code?

Comment: Please refer to the two links for benchmarks of many possible solutions.